# In Neo4j,Is it possible to use Python to find a node by its ID and perform an operation?

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j,Is it possible to use Python to find a node by its ID and perform an operation?
[image]
Above, is the knowledge graph constructed by me. What I want to do is use Python to form a formula "t2-t1>6" based on the ids of the nodes "t1" and" t2 ".
thank u for help.

Comment: MATCH (t1:Temperature{id:"T1"}), (t2:Teperature{id:"T2})
RETURN t1.value - t2.value > 6

I am assuming T1 and T2 are your identifiers (id property) and that the temperature reading is stored as a number in the value property.

Comment: How do you do that in Python? As you said, T1 and T2 are my identifiers(id property).And how to form the formula " t1-t2 >6"  from id(id from neo4j) in Python ?

Comment: You will get quality answer if you have details on your question. In your example,  T1 and T2 are nodes and T2 - T1 > 6 does not makes sense. You cannot do operations on nodes itself.

Comment: I just updated my question, I wonder if you can understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a query that first matches your temperature nodes and then return the result of your expression:

```
with driver.session(database = "neo4j") as session:
    result = session.read_transaction(lambda tx: 
        tx.run(
            """
            MATCH (t1:Temperature{id: $id1}), (t2:Temperature{id: $id2}) 
            RETURN t1.value - t2.value > 6 as myBooleanResult
            """,
            id1="T1", id2="T2").single()["myBooleanResult"]
        )
    print(result)
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. What does mybooleanresult mean?      when I use your code,TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: "myBooleanResult" is the "return column" of the query. If you get "NonType" object is not subscriptable, it most likely is because your query did not match any nodes/did not return any result rows.